# disable scrolling in a UITableView (iPhone SDK 3.0)

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm trying to disable scrolling in a `UITableView` when editing a `UITextField` embedded in a `UITableViewCell`.
This is just to prevent the cell from being scrolled out of sight when edited (and also to avoid some related cell "Recycling" problems).
While googling around I've seen that somebody suggested the obvious:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO:
```

or even

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This does not work though (at least for me... iPhone SDK 3.0, tried on simulator)
I set these properties to NO, I even check by logging that the properties are set to NO, but the UITableView keeps on responding normally to touch events.
And it also happily scrolls.
I wouldn't be that worried if somebody on the net were not claiming that this actually works.

Am I missing something?
Or is the only alternative subclassing UITableView to make a functionality available in its superclass (UIScrollView) work again?

Answer (score 49):

Did you try using
`self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`?

I've often tried that code from the web didn't work, simply because of a lack of the prefix self. I just tried this out without a problem.

I don't know if this work when turning it on and off dynamically. It does at least work for permanent settings when initializing the object...

Answer (score 18):

If you're using `UITableViewController`, you also have a `tableView` property, with no casting needed. This works for me:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: yes it works bro,why do people only ask question and never think of giving tick for right ans?

Comment: This did not work for my case. Only calling the setScrollEnabled method is working for me. Not that that makes sense since under the hood they should be executing the same code.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try on storyboard unselect scrolling enabled?

[image: Scrolling Enabled : NO]

Answer (score 2):

I tried:

```
[(UIScrollView*)[self view] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

and it worked ([self view] is my view of the current view controller, i.e., a UITableView).

The thing is, I get a warning:

'UIScrollView' may not respond to '-setScrollingEnabled:'

In all honesty, the property is "scrollEnabled", but it works nonetheless with the aforementioned code!

So, the "right" way to do things, should be:

```
[(UIScrollView*)[self view] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Why it also works the other way, is confusing me...

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked in my case. Table view kept scrolling ever though every scrollView was disabled.

Finally, I've found solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004781/override-automatic-scrolling-in-uitextview), claiming that `UITableViewController` does this "for me" whenever keyboard hides the UITextView being edit.

Solution is to inherit from `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` and implement the required table functionality myself.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to scroll only if its content is not visible then set:

**yourTableview.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;**

Here if your content is visible then your tableview will not scroll