# Override automatic scrolling in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view in a note-taking application I'm creating that is composed of a UITableView with a UITextView as a custom UITableViewCell (among other things). I know that having a UIScrollView within another UIScrollView is generally not recommended but I don't see a better way to do it for my purposes.

At any rate, the issue I'm having right now is that the UITextView, despite having scrolling disabled, is still affecting the scrolling of the UITableView itself. In other words, when I enter text into the UITextView or select it, the UITableView is scrolled automatically by the UITextView. Sometimes it works as desired, scrolling appropriately to the selected text, but more often than not it does not, generally scrolling to the bottom of the UITextView cell (which is not at all what I want). So I've been trying to handle the scrolling manually or finding a way to make it work automatically, but so far I've had no luck.

I've been searching for solutions here and on Google for days but I haven't come up with anything that works. I've tried simply scrolling to the desired area in the `textViewDidBeginEditing` method or by intercepting the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification, but neither produces the desired effect - the former scrolls after the UITextView has already automatically scrolled, the latter before (and so the automatic scrolling still occurs either way).

I've also tried subclassing the UITextView being used in the cell and overriding all scroll methods (ie. `scrollRectToVisible`), but this does not appear to prevent the automatic scrolling either. I've tried adjusting the frame of the UITableView when the UITextView is in use, which only made things worse.

So the conclusion I've come to is that I have to somehow disable all automatic scrolling in the UITextView, or prevent the two from communicating somehow. I've been trying to find a way to do this though and I haven't had any luck so far. Does anyone know how to do this or have an alternative solution to my issue? I'd really appreciate any help possible here.

Below is the code I think pertains to this issue. I'd be happy to provide any more if it helps. Also, this is my first iOS application, so forgive me if there is some poor technique in my code or if there is something I've overlooked.

UITableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell = [self cellForTitleCell:indexPath withTableView:tableView];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = [self cellForBodyCell:indexPath withTableView:tableView];
            break;
        default:
            cell = [self cellForListCell:indexPath withTableView:tableView];
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForBodyCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withTableView: (UITableView *) tableView
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoteViewBodyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *bodyText = note.Body;

    float frameHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    frameHeight += self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    frameHeight += self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
    if (bodyTextView == nil)
    {
        bodyTextView = [[BodyTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,  460 - frameHeight)];
        bodyTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        bodyTextView.text = bodyText;
        bodyTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        bodyTextView.editable = YES;
        bodyTextView.delegate = self;
        bodyTextView.tag = 6;

        CGSize bodySize = [bodyTextView.text sizeWithFont:bodyTextView.font
                                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width-20, 9999) 
                                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        CGRect bodyFrame = bodyTextView.frame;
        if (bodySize.height < 460 - frameHeight)
            bodySize.height = 460 - frameHeight;
        bodyFrame.size.height = bodySize.height;
        bodyTextView.frame = bodyFrame;

        bodyTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:bodyTextView];
    cell.frame = bodyTextView.frame;
    bodyTextView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight;
    CGSize bodyTextSize;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            rowHeight = 40;
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([self isStringEmpty:bodyTextView.text])
                bodyTextSize = [note.Body sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width-20, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            else
                bodyTextSize = bodyTextView.contentSize;
            if (bodyTextSize.height < 460 - 128)
                rowHeight = 460 - 128;
            else
                rowHeight = bodyTextSize.height;            
            break;
        default:
            rowHeight = 40;
            break;
    }
    return rowHeight;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    CGRect bodyFrame = bodyTextView.frame;
    bodyFrame.size.height = bodyTextView.contentSize.height;
    if (bodyFrame.size.height < 460 - 128)
        bodyFrame.size.height = 460 - 128;
    bodyTextView.frame = bodyFrame;
}
```

UITextView (subclass):

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // do nothing
}

- (UIEdgeInsets) contentInset 
{ 
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero; 
}

- (void)scrollRangeToVisible:(NSRange)range
{
    // do nothing
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // do nothing
}

- (BOOL) isScrollEnabled
{
    return NO;
}
```

Some methods I've tried (found on StackOverflow):

```
// tried calling this method in both textViewDidBeginEditing and keyboardWillShow
- (BOOL)scrollToCursor
{
    // if there is a selection cursor…
    if(bodyTextView.selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSLog(@"selectedRange: %d %d", bodyTextView.selectedRange.location, bodyTextView.selectedRange.length);

        // work out how big the text view would be if the text only went up to the cursor
        NSRange range;
        range.location = bodyTextView.selectedRange.location;
        range.length = bodyTextView.text.length - range.location;
        NSString *string = [bodyTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
        CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:bodyTextView.font constrainedToSize:bodyTextView.bounds.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        // work out where that position would be relative to the textView's frame
        CGRect viewRect = bodyTextView.frame;  
        int scrollHeight = viewRect.origin.y + size.height;
        CGRect finalRect = CGRectMake(1, scrollHeight, 1, 1);

        // scroll to it
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:finalRect animated:YES];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO CURSOR");
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([bodyTextView isFirstResponder])
    {
        NSLog(@"starting to change scroll view");

        // Get the keyboard size
        CGRect keyboardBounds;
        [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

        // Detect orientation
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;

        // Start animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

        // Reduce size of the Table view 
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.height;
        else 
            frame.size.height -= keyboardBounds.size.width;
        frame.size.height += keyboardToolbar.frame.size.height;

        // Apply new size of table view
        self.tableView.frame = frame;

        // Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
        if (self.bodyTextView)
        {
            CGRect textViewRect = [self.tableView convertRect:bodyTextView.bounds fromView:bodyTextView];
            [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:textViewRect animated:NO];
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    isKeyboardVisible = YES;
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([bodyTextView isFirstResponder])
    {
        // Get the keyboard size
        CGRect keyboardBounds;
        [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

        // Detect orientation
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

        // Reduce size of the Table view 
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.height;
        else 
            frame.size.height += keyboardBounds.size.width;

        // Apply new size of table view
        self.tableView.frame = frame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    isKeyboardVisible = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe most of the `UITableView`'s automatic scrolling code resides in the `UITableViewController`. For example, if you have a `UITextField` in one of the table rows that is towards the bottom of the screen, the table automatically scrolls upwards to make way for the keyboard when the user taps on the `UITextField`. As you want to minimize auto-scrolling, I would suggest not using the `UITableViewController`. Instead, just subclass `UIViewController` & make it implement `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource`. That being said, you would also miss out on some of the good things that `UITableViewController` provides.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Thank you so much! You are exactly right, using a UIViewController seems to have prevented all automatic scrolling from the UITextView. Now I can FINALLY get scrolling working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is bodyTextView the text view that you are trying to scroll/not scroll? If so, are you setting it's delegate somewhere else in your code? Meaning, do you have something like `bodyTextView.delegate = self;` somewhere? If you haven't set its delegate, that may be while it's not responding to some of your code. To be able to do this, subscribe to the text view delegate by adding `<UITextViewDelegate>` to your header file, along with setting its delegate as I explained.

Comment: Yes, I have `bodyTextView.delegate = self;` in the `cellForBodyCell` method (to initialize the bodyTextView and its cell). It definitely responds to delegate methods, of that I'm sure.

I am trying to scroll the tableView though, since bodyTextView is a subview of a UITableViewCell and so I intentionally have set it not to scroll. However, bodyTextView affects the scrolling behaviour of the tableView in ways I do not intend, and I have not found a way to fix it, which is why I am frustrated by this.

Comment: I see bodyTextView.scrollEnabled = NO; inside if (cell == nil). Try taking it outside (put it after your if (cell == nil) block) and tell me what happens. EDIT: also put the line where you set its delegate after the if (cell == nil) line.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately did not seem to help. Assigning the delegate before if (cell == nil) resulted in the delegate not being properly assigned in some cases, so I placed it after the if (cell == nil) block instead. But the same issues remain. It's not that bodyTextView itself is scrolling within the UITableViewCell, it's that bodyTextView is automatically scrolling the UITableView itself, and in doing so is often scrolling away from where I want the UITableView to be scrolling to. Which is why I'm trying to prevent bodyTextView from scrolling tableView.

Comment: Maybe disable the ability for the table view to scroll before the text view scrolls, and then re-enabling the ability for the table view after the text view has been scrolled? Sorry, I don't have a solution for your problem, I've never encountered this before...