# Locking UITable scrolling after button pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disable scrolling in a UITableView (iPhone SDK 3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237355/disable-scrolling-in-a-uitableview-iphone-sdk-3-0)

I would like to ask if it is possible to lock the scrolling of UITAble after a button is pressed? is there any code for that?

Below is my code, i want to scroll the UITAble to top then user will not be able to scroll down anymore.

```
- (IBAction)export:(id)sender{


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                  animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to add prefix `self` in below code..

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Hope, this will you..